# How I can create timer in classic asp?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am developing a application using classic asp and I need to call face book graph API with in every 15 minutes.

I knew I can do this using set interval function, but it will work only when page will open in browser.

I am using MySQL DB. can I do this using any db Job which run simultaneously after every 15 minutes.

Please suggest me your valuable suggestion.

Comment: You'd want to do that client side, really, then post back to a server. [JavaScript](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) is your friend.

Comment: No browser eh? Perhaps write a .vb (WSH) to perform an HttpRequest hitting your classic ASP page, and run that .vb every 15 mins inside a Scheduled Task ?

Comment: I have suggestion to stop using classic ASP

Comment: If you need to run a task repeatedly that does not require any client interaction then there is no reason to use ASP (or *any* web server). Just set up a scheduled task in your favorite scripting language and let it run every 15 minutes.